# Updating code in Oracle taking too much time

Tags: sql, oracle

I am running the following code for 40000 rows

```
update L02_A_AVOX_DATA
set PWC_Exclusion_Flag = (select PWC_Exclusion_Flag from result
where L02_A_AVOX_DATA.PWC_SEQ_AVOX = result.PWC_SEQ_AVOX);
```

The code is running for 20 minutes . Dont know whats the error.
Can anyone help me in it

Comment: Please have a look at the Explain Plan.

Comment: 40,000 rows is in the target table, or you expect 40,000 rows to be updated? How many rows are in `result`? Are you certain there are no uncommitted transactions against the table?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try the following query, maybe that helps:

```
MERGE INTO L02_A_AVOX_DATA n USING (
    SELECT PWC_Exclusion_Flag , PWC_SEQ_AVOX
      FROM result
) o ON (n.PWC_SEQ_AVOX = o.PWC_SEQ_AVOX)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE SET n.PWC_Exclusion_Flag = o.PWC_Exclusion_Flag;
```